# How set the selected option on a dynamic loaded secondary select with VueJS?

Tags: ajax, laravel-blade, vue.js, vue-resource

I have a city select:

```
<select v-model="city">
    <option value="" selected>CIDADE AONDE VOCÊ ESTUDA</option>
    <option value="city1">City 1</option>
    <option value="city2">City 2</option>
    <option value="cityx">City x</option>
</select>
```

And a a school select:

```
<select v-model="school">
    <option
        v-for="item in schools"
        v-bind:value="item.name"
        v-bind:selected="school == item.name"
    >
        @{{ item.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

This is the data (filled by a Laravel Blade view), which may or may not come with a city and a school:

```
data: {
    ...
    city: '{{ Input::old('city') }}',
    school: '{{ Input::old('school') }}',
    schools: [],
},
```

I also have a watch on city:

```
watch: {
    'city': '__cityChanged',
},
```

This is the event handler:

```
__cityChanged: function (event)
{
    this.school = '';

    this.__fetchSchools();
},
```

And the fetcher:

```
__fetchSchools: function (event)
{
    if (this.city)
    {
        this.$http.get('/schools/' + this.city, function (schools)
        {
            this.schools = schools;
        });
    }
},
```

Almost everything works fine, the only problem is, when the form is reloaded (or redirected back on a failed validation) and city and a school are already selected, it does call the `__fetchSchools` and fill up the schools select correctly, but it does not set the school selected option, so what the user sees is the school unselected.

Is there a way to make it work using Vue?

Comment: Side note: `school: '{{ Input::old('school') }}',` will break if there's a `'` in the school's name. `school: {!! json_encode(Input::old('school')) !!},` will render it safe. Same thing for city name.

Comment: It doesn't, I forgot to say it's a Laravel thing, but, got it working. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a work for state management. check [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the `__cityChanged` handler, this is the fix:

```
__cityChanged: function (event)
{
    var city = '{{ Input::old('city') ?: (isset($subscription) ? $subscription->city : '') }}';

    if (this.city !== city)
    {
        this.school = '';
    }

    this.__fetchSchools();
},
```